# Subdivision deforms mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, hair

#### Problem

I tried to subdivide part of the mesh so I can add more hair particles to the scalp, and as I added more subdivisions to the mesh it started to deform into an interesting pattern, I want the head to be smooth like before.

[image]

Comment: hello, we can't see your image  ;)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Hello, the question has now been updated, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is because subdivide command works differently than subdivision surface modifier's catmull-clark algorithm

Comment: You could, for example, P -> Separate by selection and use subd modifier, if you have seams marked correctly, but even then I'm not sure the results would line up exactly

Comment: You could also look at the lower left panel after running one subdivide, there's a "smooth" option, as well as making more cuts with a single command.

Comment: The smoothing seems to work, but the lines are still there.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/zsWwhvB/image.png